# por que python cambia los valores al momento de realizar cálculos?

Tags: python

Tengo un problema al calcular los valores por eliminación de *Gauss*; leer archivo solo genera 4 vectores para llenar la matriz y el vector solución.

Crear matriz solo llena la matriz y el vector solución y al momento de calcular Gauss, *python* agarra valores que no existen, haciendo que la solución sea otra y no entiendo el por que.

```
1142 1060  325  201
 863  995   98   98
1065 3205   23  162
 554  120    0   54
 983 2896  120  138
 256  485   88   61
```

Estos son los datos de prueba y abajo los valores que debería de mostrar en los betas

> ```
>    B0 = 6.7013 B1 = 0.0784 B2 = 0.0150 B3 = 0.2461
> ```

```
import math

class Archivo:

    def leerArchivo(self,nombreArchivo):
        datosW = []
        datosX = []
        datosY = []
        datosZ = []
        iterador = 0
        archivo = open(nombreArchivo,"r")
        for linea in archivo.readlines():
            separarDatos = linea.split()
            datosW.append(float(separarDatos[0]))
            datosX.append(float(separarDatos[1]))
            datosY.append(float(separarDatos[2]))
            datosZ.append(float(separarDatos[3]))
        archivo.close()
        return datosW,datosX,datosY,datosZ

class CalcularBetas:

    def crearMatriz(self,vectorW,vectorX,vectorY,vectorZ):
        sumatoriaW=sumatoriaX=sumatoriaY=sumatoriaZ = 0.0
        wCuadrada=xCuadrada=yCuadrada=zCuadrada = 0.0
        wPorX=wPorY=wPorZ=xPorY=xPorZ=yPorZ = 0.0


        for iterador in range(len(vectorW)):
            sumatoriaW += vectorW[iterador]
            sumatoriaX += vectorX[iterador]
            sumatoriaY += vectorY[iterador]
            sumatoriaZ += vectorZ[iterador] 

            wCuadrada += pow(vectorW[iterador],2)
            xCuadrada += pow(vectorX[iterador],2)
            yCuadrada += pow(vectorY[iterador],2)

            wPorX += vectorW[iterador] * vectorX[iterador]
            wPorY += vectorW[iterador] * vectorY[iterador]
            wPorZ += vectorW[iterador] * vectorZ[iterador]
            xPorY += vectorX[iterador] * vectorY[iterador]
            xPorZ += vectorX[iterador] * vectorZ[iterador]
            yPorZ += vectorY[iterador] * vectorZ[iterador]

        numeroDatos = len(vectorW)
        matrizBetas = [[numeroDatos,sumatoriaW,sumatoriaX,sumatoriaY],
                [sumatoriaW,wCuadrada,wPorX,wPorY],
                [sumatoriaX,wPorX,xCuadrada,xPorY],
                [sumatoriaY,wPorY,xPorY,yCuadrada]]     

        vectorResultados = [sumatoriaZ,wPorZ,xPorZ,yPorZ]

        return matrizBetas,vectorResultados

    def calcularGauss(self,matrizDeBetas,vectorResultados):
        size = 4
        resultados = [0,0,0,0]
        for recorre in range(0,size):
            for renglon in range(recorre+1,size):
                factor=(matrizDeBetas[renglon][recorre]/matrizDeBetas[recorre][recorre])
                print(matrizDeBetas[renglon][recorre], matrizDeBetas[recorre][recorre], renglon,recorre)
                vectorResultados[renglon]=vectorResultados[renglon]-(factor*vectorResultados[recorre])
            for columnas in range(0,size):
                matrizDeBetas[renglon][columnas]=matrizDeBetas[renglon][columnas]-(factor*matrizDeBetas[recorre][columnas])
        resultados[size-1]=vectorResultados[size-1]/matrizDeBetas[size-1][size-1]

        for renglon in range(size-2,-1,-1):
            suma = 0
            for columnas in range(0,size):
                suma=suma+matrizDeBetas[renglon][columnas]*resultados[columnas]
            resultados[renglon]=(vectorResultados[renglon]-suma)/matrizDeBetas[renglon][renglon]
        return resultados

class Programa5: #m
    datosW = []
    datosX = []
    datosY = []
    datosZ = []
    vectorResultados = []
    resultadoHoras = 0
    resultados = []


    archivo = Archivo() #b
    calculos = CalcularBetas()
    nombreArchivo = input("ingresa el nombre del archivo de prueba: ") #b
    datosW,datosX,datosY,datosZ = archivo.leerArchivo(nombreArchivo)#b
    matriz,vectorResultados = calculos.crearMatriz(datosW,datosX,datosY,datosZ)
    resultados = calculos.calcularGauss(matriz,vectorResultados)

    lineasAgregadas = float(input("ingrese las lineas agregadas "))
    lineasReusadas = float(input("ingrese las lineas reusadas "))
    lineasModificadas = float(input("ingrese las lineas modificadas "))

    resultadoHoras = resultados[0]+(resultados[1]*lineasAgregadas)+(resultados[2]*lineasReusadas)+(resultados[3]*lineasModificadas)

    print("B0",resultados[0],"B1",resultados[1],"B2",resultados[2],"B3",resultados[3])
    print(resultadoHoras," horas")
```

Comment: No se entiende qué es lo que se supone que debería hacer, pero si lo que te extraña es que el `print()` dentro de la función `calcularGauss()` muestre números raros que originalmente no estaban en `matrizDeBetas`, la razón es que estás modificando esa matriz cuatro líneas más abajo.

Answer (score 0):

### Cuestiones de estilo

Lo primero que me ha llamado la atención de tu código es que hayas usado clases para todo, cuando en realidad nada en tu código requiere programación orientada a objetos, ya que no hay estado que guardar en los objetos. Eso se puede observar porque todos tus métodos requieren un parámetro `self` (que se referiría a la instancia del objeto) y que sin embargo no usan.

Podrías definir esos métodos como "estáticos", poniendo delante `@staticmethod`, lo que indicaría que no necesitan de una instancia del objeto para ejecutarse sino que directamente se pueden ejecutar sobre la clase. Eso te evitaría declarar el parámetro `self` que no necesitas, es decir, sería:

```
class Archivo:
    @staticmethod
    def leerArchivo(nombreArchivo):
        ...
```

Y para usarlo no necesitarías ya instanciar un objeto de la clase `Archivo()`, sino que directamente harías:

```
nombreArchivo = input("ingresa el nombre del archivo de prueba: ")
datosW,datosX,datosY,datosZ = Archivo.leerArchivo(nombreArchivo)
```

Pero es que ni eso veo necesario. ¿Por qué meter todas esas funciones como métodos de clase? Directamente pueden ser funciones "sin más", fuera de las clases.

Después está lo del "programa principal". Has escrito algo como esto:

```
class Programa5: #m
    # Varias lineas
    # de codigo python
    # conteniendo inputs, prints
    # y llamadas a otras funciones
```

Es decir, en esencia algo equivalente a:

```
class ProgramaPrincipal:
      print("Hola mundo")
```

Es la primera vez que veo algo así y lo primero que pensé fue que no funcionaría, pues el código que has escrito *no está dentro de ningún método*, sino directamente dentro de la zona de los atributos de la clase.

Curiosamente sí que funciona. Ese código es ejecutado porque se ve que Python lo considera una expresión a evaluar, porque su resultado podría ser un atributo de clase, es decir algo como `atributo = "valor"`, pero en este caso el resultado de la expresión (`print()` en el ejemplo anterior) no se asigna.

En definitiva, que funciona "casi por casualidad" y desde luego no es la forma de encapsular el código del "programa principal". Lo habitual es, o bien poner ese código fuera de toda clase y toda función (es decir, sin indentación), o bien meterlo dentro de una función llamada por ejemplo `main()` que después ejecutarías al final del fuente. Así:

```
def main():
    # codigo
    # del programa
    # principal

main()
```

O siguiendo otro patrón muy común:

```
def main():
    # codigo
    # del programa
    # principal

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Que hace que esa función se ejecute cuando lanzas el script con python, pero no cuando usas ese código como un módulo que es importado desde otro.

### Tu pregunta

Al margen de todo lo anterior, tu pregunta trataba de los valores de B0, etc que no te salen como esperabas. Por desgracia no sé qué operación es la que intentas computar en tu función `calcularGauss()`. Necesitaría que explicaras el algoritmo de lo que estás intentado hacer, para poder entender qué estás haciendo mal.

Aún sin tenerlo claro, puedo ver alguna cosa rara en ese código, como que usas la varieble `renglon`, que era un índice en un bucle *una vez que ya has salido de ese bucle*. No sé si eso es correcto (la variable aún tendría el valor de la última iteración) pero me resulta sospechoso.

### Propuesta de mejora

Dejando de lado la función `calcularGauss()` para la que necesitaría más información, te ofrezco a continuación otro diseño del código que tenías (de momento hace exactamente lo mismo y da el mismo resultado).

En él he eliminado las clases, he puesto una función `main()`, y he alterado un poco las funciones de leer archivo y componer la matriz, para hacerlas más "pythónicas":

```
import math

def leerArchivo(nombreArchivo):
    lineas = []   # Cada elemento de esta lista será otra lista de floats, una por línea
    with open(nombreArchivo,"r") as archivo:
        for linea in archivo:
            lineas.append([float(x) for x in linea.split()])

    # El truco siguiente "transpone" la matriz de líneas leidas
    datosW, datosX, datosY, datosZ = list(zip(*lineas))
    return datosW, datosX, datosY, datosZ

def crearMatriz(vectorW,vectorX,vectorY,vectorZ):
    # Hacemos uso de sum() y expresiones generadoras para computar
    # todas estas cantidades
    sumatoriaW = sum(vectorW)
    sumatoriaX = sum(vectorX)
    sumatoriaY = sum(vectorY)
    sumatoriaZ = sum(vectorZ)
    wCuadrada = sum(w**2 for w in vectorW)
    xCuadrada = sum(x**2 for x in vectorX)
    yCuadrada = sum(y**2 for y in vectorY)
    wPorX = sum(w*x for w,x in zip(vectorW, vectorX))
    wPorY = sum(w*y for w,y in zip(vectorW, vectorY))
    wPorZ = sum(w*z for w,z in zip(vectorW, vectorZ))
    xPorY = sum(x*y for x,y in zip(vectorX, vectorY))
    xPorZ = sum(x*z for x,z in zip(vectorX, vectorZ))
    yPorZ = sum(y*z for y,z in zip(vectorY, vectorZ))

    numeroDatos = len(vectorW)
    matrizBetas = [ [numeroDatos, sumatoriaW, sumatoriaX, sumatoriaY],
                    [sumatoriaW, wCuadrada, wPorX, wPorY],
                    [sumatoriaX, wPorX, xCuadrada, xPorY],
                    [sumatoriaY, wPorY, xPorY, yCuadrada]]

    vectorResultados = [ sumatoriaZ, wPorZ, xPorZ, yPorZ]

    return matrizBetas,vectorResultados

def calcularGauss(matrizDeBetas,vectorResultados):
    # Esta función no sé lo que se supone que debe hacer, así que no la he tocado
    size = 4
    resultados = [0,0,0,0]
    for recorre in range(0,size):
        for renglon in range(recorre+1,size):
            factor=(matrizDeBetas[renglon][recorre]/matrizDeBetas[recorre][recorre])
            print(matrizDeBetas[renglon][recorre], matrizDeBetas[recorre][recorre], renglon,recorre)
            vectorResultados[renglon]=vectorResultados[renglon]-(factor*vectorResultados[recorre])
        for columnas in range(0,size):
            # pero es raro que uses en la expresión siguiente el valor de renglon y de factor
            # ¿Quizás este bucle debería estar anidado en el anterior?
            matrizDeBetas[renglon][columnas]=matrizDeBetas[renglon][columnas]-(factor*matrizDeBetas[recorre][columnas])
    resultados[size-1]=vectorResultados[size-1]/matrizDeBetas[size-1][size-1]

    for renglon in range(size-2,-1,-1):
        suma = 0
        for columnas in range(0,size):
            suma=suma+matrizDeBetas[renglon][columnas]*resultados[columnas]
        resultados[renglon]=(vectorResultados[renglon]-suma)/matrizDeBetas[renglon][renglon]
    return resultados

def main():
    # Función principal
    nombreArchivo = input("ingresa el nombre del archivo de prueba: ") #b
    datosW,datosX,datosY,datosZ = leerArchivo(nombreArchivo)#b

    matriz,vectorResultados = crearMatriz(datosW,datosX,datosY,datosZ)
    resultados = calcularGauss(matriz,vectorResultados)

    lineasAgregadas = float(input("ingrese las lineas agregadas "))
    lineasReusadas = float(input("ingrese las lineas reusadas "))
    lineasModificadas = float(input("ingrese las lineas modificadas "))
    resultadoHoras = resultados[0]+(resultados[1]*lineasAgregadas)+(resultados[2]*lineasReusadas)+(resultados[3]*lineasModificadas)

    print("B0",resultados[0],"B1",resultados[1],"B2",resultados[2],"B3",resultados[3])
    print(resultadoHoras," horas")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Ejecutar la función principal al arrancar el programa
    main()
```

Comment: el programa lo hice asi porque asi me lo piden porque hay clases anteriores que se reutilizaron en este codigo, en cuanto a mi pregunta lo solucione y al parecer usted tambien, el bucle que menciono que deberia de estar anidado es el que tenia mal

for columnas in range(0,size): 

es el que deberia de estar anidado al anterior y eso soluciono el problema de calculos, su respuesta fue muy util, muchas gracias